# Report on form submission

Tags: reports

I was wondering if it is possible to generate some statistics on how many people have completed our newsletter subscription form (which runs as a Drupal webform with various custom fields, we have quite a complicated setup for different newsletters in various languages). It would be cool to be able to share with staff how many signups we are getting each month to be able to spot trends etc.

Thanks!

Comment: if they are coming off a number of different webforms then I would go down the 'build a View' route - or via SearchKit you may be able to use the 'source' field as this could be unique for each webform

Answer (score 1):

You can just get this from the webform results tab. It's in a different spot for drupal 7 vs 8, but both have a results table. You can also download it.